# PowerBI : creating a table using SelectedValue from various columns in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, selectedvalue

I am new to DAX functions.
I have a freights table  with 6 columns `(vehicleclass,count,avg,peakperiod,capturedate,daytype)`.  I need a new column `(hgvAMCount)` to include selected values from `vehicleclass(hgv)`, `count`, and `peakperiod (AM)`

I created a DAX measure `hgvcolum`:

```
hgvAMCount= SELECTEDVALUE (
            'freights'[vehicleclass],
            "**hgv**",
           'freights'[count],
            "**count**",
            'freights'[peakperiod],
            "**AM**"
        )
```

I am getting this error:

> Too many arguments were passed to the selectedvalue function. The maximum argument count for the function is 2

I am not sure if I am using the right DAX function, I used `SELECTEDVALUE`, but it's not working. I also tried to merge columns.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to use [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function) as some sort of lookup function (not what it's for).

I'd guess you're looking for something more like this:

```
hgvAMCount =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'freights'[count] ),
    'freights'[vehicleclass] = "hgv",
    'freights'[peakperiod] = "AM"
)
```

Comment: Thankyou it did work but when i tried to include other freights information , it did not work. For example 'freights'[vehicleclass] = "hgv","lgv","non-freight".